# Change Terminal in Dock to Show Open Windows Instead of Open Tabs

Tags: terminal, dock

I heavily use *Terminal.app* as I am a software engineer. While working, I can have over a dozen terminal tabs open spread across multiple terminal windows. When I have this large amount of tabs open, the right-click menu of the docked *Terminal.app* becomes really cluttered. I have attached screenshots illustrating this.

[image: 12 Terminal Tabs on 3 Windows]

[image: Cluttered Dock Context Menu]

What I am hoping to do is change how the context menu works to show open **windows** instead of **tabs**.

For Reference, I am running macOS High Sierra (10.13.3).

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: (1) Which version of OsX? On El Capitan the terminal icon gives access to the Windows, not the tabs (and you can use command+number to switch) (2) have you considered using iTerm2? https://iterm2.com/

Comment: @GioValerio I am using macOS High Sierra (10.13.3). Updating Question to include this.

Comment: @Andrew I am also facing the same issue.Have you found any solution for this? I am using 10.13.4.

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this? :)